# ArrayObjectAdapter drawing the items twice (Android TV)

Tags: android, android-tv

I'm building an Android TV app for which I've rewritten the `loadRows()` method as such:

```
    private void loadRows(String[] CATEGORY_LIST) {
    mRowsAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(new ListRowPresenter());


    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS; i++) {

        ArrayObjectAdapter listRowAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(new ListRowPresenter());
        HeaderItem header = new HeaderItem(i, CATEGORY_LIST[i]);
        mRowsAdapter.add(new ListRow(header, listRowAdapter));


    }

    setAdapter(mRowsAdapter);

}
```

My problem is that the `CATEGORY_LIST` is being drawn twice: once when the app is launched, and once on a right arrow press.

When it is drawn on the right arrow press, the spaces between the items are a little bit bigger, so I assume that is a "feature" from `ArrayObjectAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 HeaderItem header1 = new HeaderItem(1, getString(R.string.pontos_title));
 ArrayObjectAdapter listRowAdapter1 = new ArrayObjectAdapter(cardPresenter);
        for (int z = 0; z < pontos.size() ; z++) {
            listRowAdapter1.add(pontos.get(z));
        }
        mRowsAdapter.add(new ListRow(header1,listRowAdapter1));
        ObjectAdapter mAdapter = getAdapter();
        mAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(1, NewObjects.size()); //Line 1
```

If you want to update the item on the same line use, but remove first.

```
mRowsAdapter.removeItems(1, LastedObjects.size());// Line 1
```